# Redirect a link from a URL with a certain string to another URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this link on my page:

```
<a href="https://community.mydomain.com/t5/custom/page/page-id/developer-zone">
```

and I need to redirect folks who click on that link to this URL:

```
https://community.mydomain.com/s/topic/0TO44000000FliLGAS/sdk
```

I'd love to be able to add some Javascript/jQuery in the head that says "if a link URL contains 'community.mydomain.com' then redirect to the new URL if the user clicks on the link." Something tells me that it's not that easy.

I've checked similar questions and I don't think specifically address what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its actually quite easy, you can await a link click with jquery and redirect then:

```js
$(function(){

$(document).on("click","a",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();//prevent google from opening
    location.href="http://stackoverflow.com";//open SO instead
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://google.com">Hi</a>
```

Comment: Will that apply to all links on the page? Or just the one I want to target?